# Putting Packet.show() representation in string variable

Tags: python, string, packet, scapy

Is it somehow possible to put the representation which `Packet.show()` gives me into a string variable?

Like this

```
representation = somePacket.show()
print representation # will print nothing
```

So I can store it for later use and print it when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.show()` just print to stdout. You need to replace `sys.stdout` with an object that can hold written strings.

For example, in the following example, `io.BytesIO` is used to capture the written string:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> from scapy.all import Ether, IP, ICMP, Net
>>> packets = Ether()/IP(dst=Net("google.com/30"))/ICMP() 
>>> old_stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, BytesIO()
>>> try:
...     packets.show()
...     output = sys.stdout.getvalue()  # retrieve written string
... finally:
...     sys.stdout = old_stdout  # Restore sys.stdout
... 
>>> output[:10]
'###[ Ether'
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. One question remaining - Will this work on windows? Might be relevant later on.

Comment: @vicco, I didn't test on windows, but am pretty sure it will work on windows.